# how to build a table of items and it's radioButtons with a dynamic size?

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, dynamic-tables

I want to build a table, with some items, and for each item I want to have its own radioButton. but the input is dynamic. so the size of the table is dynamic, and the "ActionCommand" for each radioButton is dynamic.
what is the best way to do this?

the only way I know is to normally just make a dynamic list of radioButtons and initialize it dynamicly with the names of the items.

thank you

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends of what you want to do after ? You have to give more details...

- If it's for printing, you can take a look about JTable (or more powerful JXTable) which can handle your data with a specific model (model which you have to define).
  Just remember to set the action command to each radio button before adding to the table. You'll have to take the time to read doc about this, but with some tests it givesa very good result !
- Else, yeah, just a map, with the name of the item, and the radio button.

Comment: I want to diplay some data (dynamic data) to the user and let him choose some items. and then just save his choises to my dataBase.

Comment: So yeah, the use of JTable or JXTable is probably what you need :) Take a look at the doc and code examples, it allows a lot of actions like choose, filter, display a list of Objects.